# Can I ask this question: what recent philosophers should I be reading?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask this question: what recent philosophers should I be reading? I would (am?) adding context:

- that I would prefer analytic work about science;
- but am also interested in general aesthetics and ethics;
- that I have a grounding in philosophy but have read little recently;
- that I'm averse to Sartre, entity realism, and political theory since Marx;
- and would want something which takes literature, nihilism, and ontological naturalism pretty seriously.

Maybe too vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is indeed not a very suitable question. For mainly two reasons:

- This would be a list question with no ultimate best answer. How should one decide for which answer to vote and for which not?
- You're specific set of interests/requirements is very localised, and therefore unlikely to help others stumbling upon your question later on.

This seems like an excellent question for the chat room.

---

Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/